# Exporting Infopath Data with Structure to Excel

Tags: infopath-2007

I have layout table in infopath form. Which has text boxes in each cells of the tables. I have Named the header row of the table because Infopath does not have label control. I want to export same structure with data to Excel. When I tried to do that, infopath exports all the layout table data just in a single row in Excel. I want to keep the structure of the Layout Table intact (5 rows and 12 columns in Infopath Layout table with data) should be rendered as a table with 5 rows and 12 columns in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Only success I've had getting an InfoPath form to Excel is to  choose "**Export to Web**" in InfoPath (2010) to create an *mht file, and then drag the *mht into Excel.